# Como ocultar uma DIV inteira baseado no ID com PHP?

Tags: php

Como posso ocultar uma `div` inteira usando `PHP`?

Supondo o HTML:

```
<div id="e_4046058" class="event active">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="eventInfo">
    <span class="StartTime">16/03/2015 16:00 WET</span>
   <input class="decValue" type="hidden" value="0.00"></div>
    <div id="b_84723885" class="selections active">
</div>
      </div>
           </div>
                   </div>
```

Esta `DIV` está vindo de um site externo, então uso o `file_get_contents` pra obter esses conteúdos.

Queria uma ajuda para saber se tem condições de ocultar toda a `div id="e_4046058"` com todo seu conteúdo.

Supondo que eu tenha duas `div` dessas:

```
<div id="div1" class="event active">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="eventInfo">
    <span class="StartTime">16/03/2015 16:00 WET</span>
   <input class="decValue" type="hidden" value="0.00"></div>
    <div id="b_84723885" class="selections active">
</div>
      </div>
           </div>
                   </div>

 <div id="div2" class="event active">
          <div class="columns">
            <div class="eventInfo">
            <span class="StartTime">16/03/2015 16:00 WET</span>
           <input class="decValue" type="hidden" value="0.00"></div>
            <div id="b_84723885" class="selections active">
        </div>
              </div>
                   </div>
                           </div>
```

Tem como ocultar toda a `div id="div1"`?
O Que devo usar pra fazer isto? `DOMDocument` dar certo?
eu não sei nenhum método que possa usar pra ocultar uma `div` baseado no `ID` da mesma.
Se tiver alguma possibilidade peço sua ajuda pra tentar criar este módulo.
Desde já obrigado!

Comment: pode usar o DOMDocument ou apenas funções de manipulação de strings como substr, str_replace, etc..

Comment: Tentei algo, mas ele ocultou só a div mesmo, e não tudo que está nela, ele simplesmente apagou a `<div id="div2" class="event active">`, mas o restante do código ficou!

Comment: se quiser usar domdocuemnt, com 4 palavras no google vc encontrará milhares de soluções em uma fração de segundos, exemplo: "php dom remove div".

Comment: Pode colocar na própria div um estilo `diplay:none`, não?

Comment: Existe também o PHPQuery: https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ Solução em PHP com usabilidade parecida com o JQuery.